# "neuter e duobus pueris" vs "neuter puer"

Tags: grammar-choice, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In LLPSI, there is the following sentence:

> Iam neuter ē duōbus pueris dormit.

I was wondering if it was equivalent to

> Neuter puer jam dormit.

If so, is there any reason to add "e duobus"?

Comment: I think the difference is roughly equivalent to the difference of these two sentences in English: 
* Neither of the two boys now sleep.
* Neither boy now sleeps.

Comment: @Adam Would you mind converting that into an answer?

Comment: Technically, it's redundant to say neuter e duobus pueris, since neuter already makes clear that there are exactly two. So, yes, that phrase is equivalent to neuter puer, which could be used instead with no real difference in meaning (though with some loss of emphasis). I would attribute the fuller expression to the personal style of the authors of LLPSI and note that the (admittedly cursory) corpus search I did turned up very few instances of forms of neuter + ex/e or de + duobus/duabus. So I'd go so far as to say that neuter puer is better classical style.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is equivalent in meaning to "Neuter puer jam dormit."

As pointed out by the comments, *duobus* is redundant, since neuter means "neither" (of two). Note that the fact that a word is unnecessary doesn't mean that it is ungrammatical. For the construction of *neuter* with *ex,* it seems Seneca the Elder can be cited as precedent ("neuter ex filiis tuis parricidium fecit", *Controversiae* 7.1).

I think the most likely reason for the use of this phrasing is because this sentence occurs in the chapter that introduces the word "neuter", and Ørberg wanted to emphasize its meaning to readers who are expected to not have prior familiarity with it. Redundancy is a valuable way to facilitate language learning. The point of LLPSI is not to present a model of eloquent classical style, but to provide an easily understandable on-ramp to aid new learners of Latin as they develop their fluent reading skills.